# $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $n!$ is divisible by $n^2+1$

Tags: divisibility, natural-numbers

Prove that exist infinitely many natural numbers $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $n!$ is divisible by $n^2+1$.

It's obvious when n is large enough $n!$ grows larger than $n^2+1$, so $n!>n^2+1$. Is it somehow beneficial in proof?

Comment: You need $n^2+1$ not to have any prime factors larger than $n$

Comment: $18^2+1|18!$ is an example

Comment: so are $21, 38, 43, 47, 57, 68, 70, 72, 73, 83, $ and $99$

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A256011

Comment: According to [oeis.org/A120416](https://oeis.org/A120416), there exist infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ divides $n!,$ because $2(5k-2)^2$ is a term for $k > 0$

Comment: Note that $n^2 + 1$ not having any prime factors larger than $n$ is necessary but not sufficient.  For example, $7^2 + 1 = 50$ has no prime factors larger than $7$ but $7! = 5040$ is not divisible by $50$.

OEIS A120416 (https://oeis.org/A120416) gives numbers such that $n^2+1$ divides $n!$.  Numbers where $n^2 + 1$ has no prime factors larger than $n$ but $n!$ is not divisible by $n^2+1$ are very rare: 7, 68, 8119, and no others below 44822.

Comment: @MichaelLugo:  according to my calculations, $41$ should be on your list but not $68$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: you're right, this is what I get for trying to figure this out by manually conparing the two OEIS sequences.  The counterexamples appear to make the sequence https://oeis.org/A183064 , described as "Numbers k such that k^2+1 = 2*p^2, p prime".

Comment: @MichaelLugo: in the spirit of my answer, one source of those numbers are prime solutions of the modified Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=-1$  where $y$ is prime.  Then $x^2+1=2\cdot y \cdot y$, but $x!$ only has one factor of $y$ because $2y \gt x$.  That is where $7, 41,$ and $8119$ come from-$5,29$ and $5741$ are prime.  The next is $47321$ because $33461$ is prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Take $n=2(5k-2)^2$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$.

Then $n^2+1$ can be written as the product of three relatively prime factors less than $n$ as follows:

$5(10k^2-6k+1)(50k^2-50k+13).$

Answer (score 4):

One way to approach it is to look for solutions of the equation $x^2-5y^2=-1$.  If we have a solution to that modified [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), we can factor $x^2+1=5\cdot y \cdot y$.  As $y \lt \frac x2$, $x!$ will have a term $y$ and another term $2y$, so if $x \gt 5$ we have $(x^2+1)|x!$

We observe $x=2,y=1$ is a solution but the factor $5$ spoils this one.  We can use [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) to find more.  Given an $(x,y)$ pair, the next is $(9x+20y,4x+9y)$, so the next is $(38,17)$ and we can produce as many as we want.  We have $38^2+1=1445=5\cdot 17 \cdot 17$ divides $38!$ because $38!$ has $5,17,34$ among the numbers multiplied to form it.

We could choose any other constant than $5$ which is greater than $4,$ nonsquare, and for which the modified Pell equation can be solved.

Comment: This is simply beautiful, thank you for this.